# What are ways that can be used to estimate correlation matrix $V$ when $cov(\epsilon)=\sigma^2 V$?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, covariance

What are ways that can be used to estimate correlation matrix $V$ when $cov(\epsilon)=\sigma^2 V$, $y = X \beta+ \epsilon$ and $\epsilon \text{~} N(0, \sigma^2 V)$

Where $V$ is a non-singular positive definite matrix.

---

Using $V$ for example $\hat{\beta}=(X' V^{-1}X)^{-1}X'V^{-1}y$.
And

$$f(y, \beta, \sigma^2)=(2 \pi \sigma)^{-n/2} |V|^{-1/2} \exp(-\frac{1}{2}(y-X \beta)^T V^{-1} (y-X \beta))$$

Comment: What is your question precisely? It sounds like you are partly providing your answer. Are you asking how to estimate $V$ when neither $V$ nor $\beta$ nor $\sigma$ are known?

Comment: @Superpronker I think my answer lies in maybe maximizing $f(y,\beta, \sigma^2)$. But there should be multiple ways to estimate $V$ I believe.

Comment: So you mean: how do I estimate $\beta$ and $\sigma$ when $V$ is unknown? In that case, I guess (feasible) GLS is one answer, if you want a linear model.

Comment: @Superpronker I think here (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estimation_of_covariance_matrices) are some derivations. $V$ is denoted $\Sigma$ there.

Comment: If you are saying that you have $N$ observations and $V$ is $N \times N$, then this will not work. If you are saying that you have panel data with $N$ observations of individuals and $T$ time periods, and $V$ is $T \times T$, then you can use feasible GLS.

Comment: There is something about the dimensions that don't make sense to me otherwise. How can $\epsilon$ have a covariance matrix if $y = X\beta + \epsilon$?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what Aitken estimators address.  The challenge is that there are so many unknowns one is trying to estimate for the general case (for symmetric V, this would be $n(n+1)/2$).  One technique I've seen is to place extra constraints on V (like a fixed V times a variable).

Searching on "Aitken estimator" brings up many good resources.